# ¿Hay alguna palabra en español para referirse a "timing"?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término

Con frecuencia leo frases en inglés que mencionan "timing". Por ejemplo:

> The wedding had a very good timing: no hurries, time for everything.

Con "timing", si lo entiendo bien, se habla de la forma en que las cosas están programadas. Algo así como que hay un encaje fantástico entre los horarios preestablecidos y lo que realmente ocurre.

Me he fijado que en español cada vez más gente usa también la palabra "timing", pero como siempre en estos casos me pregunto: ¿no tiene nuestro idioma una forma más nativa de decir lo mismo?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"Timing" se usa en dos circunstancias principales. Una es la que dice en tu ejemplo:

> The wedding had a very good timing: no hurries, time for everything

En ese caso decimos que la boda estuvo **bien planeada**. Si se planeaba mal no iba a haber tiempo para todo lo planeado.

Otro uso muy común que se le da a "timing", es el siguiente:

> The wedding had a very good timing: there was a huge storm the
>   following day.

En ese caso decimos que la boda fue **oportuna**. Si se planeaba para el día siguiente iba a llover en la boda.

En conclusión, si bien no hay palabra nativa para "timing", siempre es mejor referirse directamente al concepto que uno quiere transmitir, no a la palabra traducida. Ya dijo Orwell en su famoso ensayo "Politics and the English Language":

> What is above all needed is to let the meaning choose the word, and not the other way around.

Comment: Gran explicación, gran cita de Orwell y fantástica foto de perfil : ) ¡Bienvenido a [spanish.se]!

Answer (score 5):

Como escribiste **no hurries** y **time for everything** deduzco que la persona hace énfasis en el tiempo. Por lo que "good timing" en ese caso significa

> **"La boda estuvo bien sincronizada, sin prisas y con tiempo para todo"**.

Como tambien puede ser

> **"La boda se llevó a cabo a tiempo, sin prisas y con tiempo para todo"**.

Se podría decir "ritmo" como lo mencionó *Diego Mijelshon* pero no es muy común decir así:

> **"La boda tuvo buen ritmo, sin prisas y con tiempo para todo"**

Sin embargo, en otro contexto sin hacer mucho énfasis en el tiempo sino en el impacto que tuvo por estar todo a tiempo y en orden. Es como en Latinoamerica se diría regularmente.

> **"La boda estuvo excelente, sin prisas y con tiempo para todo"**

Answer (score 4):

Creo que `ritmo` funciona bien en este caso.

> con buen ritmo.

Comment: ¿Puede expandir su respuesta con algunos ejemplos, o referencias?, aportará mas _contenido_ a su respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

También puede ser **distribución**.

> **[distribuir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DzLicOv)**
>
> **2.** Dar a algo su oportuna colocación o el destino conveniente.

Y para ser precisos, especificamos que se trata de distribución en el tiempo:

> *La boda tuvo una excelente **distribución temporal**.*

Answer (score 0):

o decir los tiempos en la boda estuvieron precisos.

si buscas remplazo más exacto en traducir esa frase, yo pondría

The wedding had a very good timing: no hurries, time for everything.

La boda tuvo una muy buena programación, sin apuros y con tiempo para todo.